# Android Firebase query listener not listening if no values in database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to `firebase` and `android`. I am trying to develop a chat app for android by using firebase.
For fetching the chats I’m using below firebase query. It’s retrieving all the messages, and working fine if the `chatId` exist.

```
mChatQuery = mFirebaseChatRef.child(chatId).orderByChild("chatId").equalTo(chatId);
mChatQuery.addChildEventListener(ChatActivity.this);
```

The problem I’m facing is query is not returning any value if the `chatId` not exist.
My question is how to identify the value is `null`, without using another query to check the `chatId` isExist?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
  DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(chatId).orderByChild("chatId").equalTo(chatId);
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
      //check if chatid is in the db
     for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            // retrieve also
     }
   }
 else{
         //does not exists, do something here
      } 

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {


     }
   });
```

You can use the above query, to retrieve the value and to check if it exists(one query) in the db. But `if(dataSnasphot.exists())` only works with valueventlistener and not childeventlistener

Comment: Not working :(  if the `chatid` not exist, `onDataChange` not even calling

Comment: remove `orderByChild("chatId").equalTo(chatId);` @Aabauser did you try it as above?

Comment: Then just check `chatid` for nullity before using in your reference.

Comment: No I can't remove `orderByChild("chatId").equalTo(chatId)`, becuse the datasnapshot getChildren have some other values also. it will affect the logic. and i have to use only `ChildEventListener` @PeterHaddad

Comment: @Aabauser okay check if `chatId` is null. But you can still keep it and use valueeventlistener, all you need is to add the for loop as in the answer

Comment: `chatId` is not `null`. if i use `valueventlistener` for each new data added listner will return the whole node again and again (duplicate data)it will affect for very  large amount of data's.

Comment: it wont return the whole node, it will return the data that satisfy this condition  `orderByChild("chatId").equalTo(chatId)` @Aabauser

Comment: @Aabauser: leave the `orderBy()...equalTo()`. A `ValueEventListener` is immediately called when the Firebase client has determined the current value. If there is no current value, `onDataChange` gets called with an empty snapshot. If `onDataChange` doesn't get called, most likely your device isn't connected to the servers. In that case the client can't determine the current value, so it won't fire.

Answer (score 3):

ChildEvent listeners can not listen to nodes which don't exist, ValueEvent Listeners can.

What you can do is, have the same query attached to a ValueEventListener.

Now see here's the trick, a firebase node can never exist with zero children.

In the onDataChange() method of the value event listener, you can have a check on the children count as displayed above and you should have the check for whether the node exists or not.

```
mChatQuery = mFirebaseChatRef.child(chatId).orderByChild("chatId").equalTo(chatId);
mChatQuery.addValueEventListener((new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()==0){
            //This indicates that the chatId doesn't exist
        }else{
            //Do what you want with the snapshot
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```